# split a string after a certain number of chars

Tags: c#, string

I would like to be able to split a string into several parts if it exceeds a certain number of characters(e.g 100). It is relatively easy, but the tricky part is that I want to split it only after a space so that it doesn't cut off some word, but rather cuts it on a space character. So the logic would be - if it is more than ~95 chars, split it at the next space character and keep doing it in a loop. Any suggestions on how to implement this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an override of `string.LastIndexOf`: [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131439.aspx)

You can call `mystring.LastIndexOf(' ', startIndex, endIndex)`.  If you use indexes `0` and `100`, you can get the last space in the first 100 characters.

Answer (score 1):

`string.LastIndexOf` might work, but it sounds to me like you want the first space after the 95th character, so you might be better off with `myString.IndexOf(' ', 95, myString.length - 95)` or something along those lines.

For example, if the space was at position 101 and you did `myString.LastIndexOf(' ', 0, 100)`, you wouldn't find the right space.